# Calculate number of contiguous hours

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet which contains a sheet called 'Classes' this contains the start (L) and end time (K) of each lesson as well as the duration (J), class code (A) and student name (B) who attends this lesson.

I have to timetable extra lessons around this timetable but students can only have a maximum of 5 hours without a break. Whilst I timetable someone else is also changing the timetable I'm working around so each day I need to be able to run a check to see if any lessons have been moved to give a student too many hours in a row.

The only way I can think to do this is some kind of loop which concats the student name and start time then compares it to a concat of student and end time.  When it finds a match it adds the durations together.  I need it to return the student and the day where they have too many hours.  I have no idea how this might be achieved in VBA bar my suggestion. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What have you tried?  Please add any code you have tried in the original post.

Comment: This makes sense to me: "I have a spreadsheet which contains a sheet called 'Classes' this contains the start (L) and end time (K) of each lesson as well as the duration (J), class code (A)."  I interpret this as: "The worksheet has one row per class with columns A, J, K and L containing data relevant to this question." I assume a class has many students but the following only allows for one student: "and student name (B) who attends this lesson."  Please explain.

Comment: Okay, so the Classes sheet contains rows whith the name of a student, then the name of the class that student attends along with the day and time they attend it.  So the same data in terms of class code, day and time will appear several times with the names of each student on the register for the class. By the same token the same class code will take place more than once during one week (the data contains all classes which take place in one week).

Comment: I haven't tried code myself as I don't know where to start, perhaps if someone could give me a pointer as to how to go about this I could try googling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry there are no images in this answer. The new system for including images introduced since I last posted an answer crashes or crashes my browser.  I will try again tomorrow.  I have tried again with no success.  I have reported the problem but doubt I will hear anything before Monday. Perhaps the answer is usable without the images. Alternatively, my profile includes an email address allowing you to request a copy of the images if you wish.

If you are going to Google for anything please make it “Excel VBA Tutorial”.  If you search for code to achieve some objective without knowing the basics of VBA, you will not recognise the code when you find.  We get questions here where the posted code is almost exactly what the questioner wants but they lack the VBA to make even a trivial change.

If you search for “Excel VBA Tutorial”, you will find many to choose from.  Try a few and then complete one that matches your learning style.  I prefer books.  I visited a good library and borrowed the most promising Excel VBA Primers to try at home.  I then bought the one I liked best as a permanent reference.  Twelve years later, I still check it now and again.  The time you spend learning the basics will quickly repay itself.

Once you know your basics, you are ready to start designing your macro.  I have created some demonstration data which matches your description:

Original data

I have added a Day column because you say the worksheet contains all classes which take place in one week.  I have made most of the classes one hour and have allowed five minutes travel time to get from one class to the next.  I do not care if this data is not very realistic; I just want something vaguely appropriate to as test data and as a discussion aid.

To find continuous blocks of lessons for a student, you need the data to be in student-day-start sequence.  I have entered “day” as Mon, Tue and so on which is convenient for a human user but means that when sorted “Fri” will come before “Mon”.  The macro treats each day independently so does not care about the sequence of days.  It may not that matter if an anomaly with Friday’s lessons is reported before one with Monday’s.  I will revisit this issue later.

It can be better to finish the design before any coding.  However, if the early stages are obvious, it is usually easier to code them immediately so you can see the data as it will be when designing the later stages.

The easiest way of getting the code for a sort is to use the macro recorder.  The macro recorder is no use for loops or if-then-else-endif but is convenient when you don’t know the syntax for a statement.

I activated worksheet “Classes” then switched the macro recorder on. (Tools -> Macro -> Record New Macro).  I selected all cells then “Data -> Sort” then specified the columns I wanted.  After sorting, I closed the macro recorder.  The code saved was:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Macro recorded 10/09/2015 by Tony Dallimore
'
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("G2") _
        , Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("L2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:= _
        xlSortNormal
End Sub
```

This is syntactically correct VBA but it is not good VBA.  The macro recorder does not know your objective; it simply records each statement in isolation.  However, tidying this up is not difficult:

```
  With Worksheets("Classes")

    .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=.Range("G2") _
        , Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=.Range("L2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:= _
        xlSortNormal

  End With
```

The above is a minimal tidy.  I have added a `With` statement to identify the target worksheet; I have remove the `Select` and have placed a period in front of `Cells` and `Range` to indicate they are subject to the `With` statement.  Don’t worry if you don’t know what I am talking about; once you have finished your tutorial, you will.

I would normally tidy up parameters but I will leave that as an exercise for you.  What I would also do is replace the column letters with names.  If you bury column letters or numbers in your code, you have a real problem when a new column is added or existing columns are re-sequenced.  I would replace the above with one of the following:

```
  Const ColClsStud As String = "B"
  Const ColClsDay As String = "G"
  Const ColClsStart As String = "L"

  With Worksheets("Classes")

    .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Range(ColClsStud & "2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                Key2:=.Range(ColClsDay & "2"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                Key3:=.Range(ColClsStart & "2"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:= _
        xlSortNormal

  End With
```

Or, my preference:

```
  Const ColClsStud As Long = 2
  Const ColClsDay As Long = 7
  Const ColClsStart As Long = 12

  With Worksheets("Classes")

    .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Cells(2, ColClsStud), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                Key2:=.Cells(2, ColClsDay), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                Key3:=.Cells(2, ColClsStart), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:= _
        xlSortNormal

  End With
```

`Const` (constant) statements mean that, if a column moves, one change fixes the macro.  My names all follow a pattern: a string of abbreviations.  For example `ColClsStud` is column-class-student.

We can now see the sorted data:

Sorted Data

I have only created data from Monday and Friday but I believe that is adequate for this answer.  As mentioned earlier, “Fri” comes before “Mon”.  This may not matter since each day of the week must be considered separately.  If it is unacceptable, the easiest solution is to write `=FIND(G2,"MonTueWedThuFri")` to an unused column of row 2 and copy down.  This will give a number (Mon->1, Tue->4, Wed->7, Thu->10, Fri->13) which can be used in the sort instead of Day.  More elegant solutions are available, particularly with VBA, if this is not adequate.

With the data in this sequence, it is easy to see how a human could work down the rows identifying blocks that exceed five hours and identifying useful gaps.  A macro could use a similar technique.  How would a macro “report” excessive blocks and useful gaps?  I thought about reports in another worksheet but decided this would be awkward since you would have to switch between the two worksheets while trying to fix problems.  I decided a good approach would be:

Marked data

Here I have coloured blocks of over five hours.  Red might be a more traditional colour but I find light yellow more restful.  There are web sites which list all Excel’s colours and how to obtain them so you can switch to an alternative colour if you do not like my choice.  I have inserted partially empty rows to report potentially useful gaps.  If you needed to use a gap, a row would be ready that would only need the minimum possible updating.

The macro below includes constants to define: start of day, end of day, gap sizes and so on.

Try my macro on your data.  Step through it and study how it recognises large blocks and gaps.  Do you agree that the technique used is similar to one a human might use?

The macro includes comments describing the purpose of each block of code but says little or nothing about the statements used to achieve those purposes.  Once you know a statement exists, it is normally easy to look it up.  I believe there is nothing in this macro which you would not find need the start of a tutorial with the exception of the functions `DateAdd` and `DateDiff`.  Again it is easy to look up functions once you know their name.  Alternatively you could search for “Excel VBA Date and Time Functions”.

Come back with questions as necessary but, the more you can find out for yourself, the faster you will develop.

I think learning to program is like learning to drive a car.  At the end of the first lesson you know you will NEVER be able to turn a wheel, move a gear stick, press one or two of three pedals, look in three mirrors and work the indicator leaver at the same time.  But a month later, you wonder what you found so difficult.

```
Option Explicit
  Const ColClsCode As Long = 1
  Const ColClsStud As Long = 2
  Const ColClsDay As Long = 7
  Const ColClsDuration As Long = 10
  Const ColClsEnd As Long = 11
  Const ColClsStart As Long = 12
  Const ColClsLast As Long = 12         ' Used for colouring problem rows

  Const ClrTooLong As Long = &H99FFFF       ' Light yellow = RGB(255,255,153)

  Const ContinuousMaximum As Long = 300     ' In minutes
  ' I assume there is a minimum gap between classes to count as a break.
  Const GapBreakMinimum As Long = 20        ' In minutes
  ' I assume the is a minimum duration for a class.  Gaps smaller than that
  ' minimum would not be useful,
  Const GapUsefulMinimum As Long = 30       ' In minutes
  ' I assume there is a start and end time for the academic day
  Const TimeDayStart As Date = #9:00:00 AM#
  Const TimeDayEnd As Date = #3:30:00 PM#
Sub IdentifyProblemsAndGaps()

  ' Within worksheet Classes:
  '  * Colour any sequence of lessons for a student that exceeds the maximum.
  '  * Insert rows for any gaps that are large enough to be filled with a new lesson.

  Dim DayCrnt As String
  Dim RowClsCodeLast As Long
  Dim RowClsStudCrntFirst As Long
  Dim RowClsStudLast As Long
  Dim RowClsCrnt As Long
  Dim StudentCrnt As String
  Dim TimeBlockEnd As Date
  Dim TimeBlockStart As Date

  ' Application.ScreenUpdating = False  ' This speeds the macro but makes debugging more difficult

  With Worksheets("Classes")

    ' Remove any colouring remaining from last run of macro.
    .Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    ' Sort rows on class code so rows with a blank class code are at the bottom
    .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Cells(2, ColClsCode), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
                OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
                DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    ' Find last used rows in class code and student columns
    RowClsCodeLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColClsCode).End(xlUp).Row
    RowClsStudLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColClsStud).End(xlUp).Row

    If RowClsStudLast > RowClsCodeLast Then
      ' There is at least one row with a student name but no class code
      ' Assume rows without a class code are to report gaps. Such rows
      ' must be deleted
      .Rows(RowClsCodeLast + 1 & ":" & RowClsStudLast).Delete
    End If

    ' Sort into Student, Day, Start tiem sequence
    .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Cells(2, ColClsStud), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                Key2:=.Cells(2, ColClsDay), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                Key3:=.Cells(2, ColClsStart), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:= _
        xlSortNormal

    RowClsCrnt = 2            ' First data row.  Assume one header row.
    TimeBlockStart = 0        ' I assume no lesson can start at midnight
    TimeBlockEnd = 0
    StudentCrnt = ""          ' No current student
    DayCrnt = ""              ' No current day

    ' The end value for a For-Loop cannot change during a loop. This code inserts
    ' rows so the end value will change. I have used a Do-Loop instead.
    Do While True
      ' When I code a routine, I create test data that covers every scenerio I can
      ' think of and I code for every scenerio I can think of. I then place
      ' "Debug.Assert False" at the top of every path through the code. As I
      ' test the code, I comment out each "Debug.Assert False" reached. If any are
      ' left at the end of testing, it implies my test data is inadequate or my
      ' code has a logic error.  Either way, it demonstrates that more testing and
      ' debugging is required
      'Debug.Assert False
      If StudentCrnt = .Cells(RowClsCrnt, ColClsStud).Value And _
         DayCrnt = .Cells(RowClsCrnt, ColClsDay).Value Then
        ' Another row for the same student day
        'Debug.Assert False
        If DateAdd("n", GapBreakMinimum, TimeBlockEnd) > .Cells(RowClsCrnt, ColClsStart).Value Then
          ' Current row is part of current block
          ' Extend current block to include it
          'Debug.Assert False
          TimeBlockEnd = .Cells(RowClsCrnt, ColClsEnd).Value
        Else
          ' Have gap within day
          'Check if block just ended is too long; report if it is.
          'Debug.Assert False
          Call ReviewBlockJustEndColourIfAppropriate(RowClsStudCrntFirst, RowClsCrnt - 1, _
                                                     TimeBlockStart, TimeBlockEnd)
          ' Check if gap is useful; report if it is.
          Call ReviewGapFillIfAppropriate(RowClsCrnt, TimeBlockEnd, _
                                          .Cells(RowClsCrnt, ColClsStart).Value, _
                                          StudentCrnt, DayCrnt)
          ' Start new block
          TimeBlockStart = .Cells(RowClsCrnt, ColClsStart).Value
          TimeBlockEnd = .Cells(RowClsCrnt, ColClsEnd).Value
          RowClsStudCrntFirst = RowClsCrnt
        End If
      Else
        ' New student or new day or first row
        If StudentCrnt <> "" Then
          'Check if block just ended is too long; report if it is.
          'Debug.Assert False
          Call ReviewBlockJustEndColourIfAppropriate(RowClsStudCrntFirst, RowClsCrnt - 1, _
                                                     TimeBlockStart, TimeBlockEnd)
          ' Check if gap between last class and end of day is useful; report if it is.
          Call ReviewGapFillIfAppropriate(RowClsCrnt, TimeBlockEnd, _
                                          TimeDayEnd, _
                                          StudentCrnt, DayCrnt)
        End If
        ' Start new block
        StudentCrnt = .Cells(RowClsCrnt, ColClsStud).Value
        If StudentCrnt = "" Then
          ' End of data
          Exit Do
        End If
        DayCrnt = .Cells(RowClsCrnt, ColClsDay).Value
        TimeBlockStart = .Cells(RowClsCrnt, ColClsStart).Value
        TimeBlockEnd = .Cells(RowClsCrnt, ColClsEnd).Value
        RowClsStudCrntFirst = RowClsCrnt
        ' Check if gap between start of day and first class is useful; report if it is.
        Call ReviewGapFillIfAppropriate(RowClsCrnt, TimeDayStart, _
                                          TimeBlockStart, _
                                          StudentCrnt, DayCrnt)
      End If
      RowClsCrnt = RowClsCrnt + 1
    Loop  ' For each data row in Classes

  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
Sub ReviewBlockJustEndColourIfAppropriate(ByVal RowBlockStart As Long, ByVal RowBlockEnd As Long, _
                                          ByVal TimeBlockStart As Date, ByVal TimeBlockEnd As Date)

  ' A continuation block of classes for a student has ended.
  ' Determine is the duration of those classes exceeds the maximum
  ' Colour classes if their duration exceeds the maximum

  Dim Duration As Long

  Duration = DateDiff("n", TimeBlockStart, TimeBlockEnd)        ' Duration in minutes
  If Duration > ContinuousMaximum Then
    'Debug.Assert False
    With Worksheets("Classes")
      .Range(.Cells(RowBlockStart, 1), _
             .Cells(RowBlockEnd, ColClsLast)).Interior.Color = ClrTooLong
    End With
  End If

End Sub
Sub ReviewGapFillIfAppropriate(ByRef RowClsCrnt As Long, _
                               ByVal TimeGapStart As Date, ByVal TimeGapEnd As Date, _
                               ByVal StudentCrnt As String, ByVal DayCrnt As String)

  ' There may be a gap above the current row.
  ' Determine if there is a gap and if it is big enough to be useful.
  ' If there is a useful gap, insert a row reporting the gap.

  Dim Duration As Long

  Duration = DateDiff("n", TimeGapStart, TimeGapEnd)    ' Duration in minutes
  If Duration >= GapUsefulMinimum Then
    ' Have a useful gap. Insert row
    'Debug.Assert False
    With Worksheets("Classes")
      .Rows(RowClsCrnt).Insert
      .Rows(RowClsCrnt).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone     ' Ensure colour nor copied from previous row
      .Cells(RowClsCrnt, ColClsStud).Value = StudentCrnt
      .Cells(RowClsCrnt, ColClsDay).Value = DayCrnt
      .Cells(RowClsCrnt, ColClsDuration).Value = Duration
    End With
    RowClsCrnt = RowClsCrnt + 1     ' Advance to what was current row
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: WOW!  Thank you so much, that was amazingly useful. I think I've got a handle on what you've done so next time hopefully I'll be able to sort things out myself.

Comment: @EmmaDancer.  At the top of this answer there are two triangles, one pointing up and one pointing down.  Since you found the answer helpful, please click the up triangle.  There is also a tick.  If this answer solved your problem, please click that tick to accept the answer.